# Undo cursor movement in Vim

Tags: vim

Let's say I have my cursor lying in the code below:

```
internal static SingleSelectList<Country, int> CreateCountrySingleSelectList(List<Country> countries, List<Airport> airPorts)
```

And the cursor is in the head of the line. Now I want to move my cursor to the second `<` of this line of code, which is in the WORD `List<Country>`, and just doing the key sequence of `f<;` will bring me there.

But what if I did something wrong by pressing another <kbd>;</kbd>, that will bring me to the next `<` in the line, which is in the word `List<Airport>`.

In this situation, how can I get back to the second <kbd><</kbd> using the minimum key strokes?

Is there a fastest way to undo cursor movements, instead of `F<` or pressing the key <kbd>h</kbd>for a very long time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reversible action of `;` is `,` so the answer to your question would be to use `,` one time.

You can look up what the command does by `:h ;`

```
;           Repeat latest f, t, F or T [count] times.   
,           Repeat latest f, t, F or T in opposite direction
            [count] times
```

Answer (score 15):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> to go back in cursor history.

http://www.rosipov.com/blog/open-previously-edited-file-in-vim/

Comment: Note this doesn't work for all movement commands. "The commands that are regarded as 'jumps' include searching, substitute and marks. Scrolling through a file is not regarded as jumping.". see https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Jumping_to_previously_visited_locations

Answer (score 6):

Contrary to Ruslan Osipov's wrong answer, the `f` motion does *not* store the previous position in the jump list (only motions that usually go to non-adjacent lines do).

But nothing prevents you from explicitly setting a jump yourself with `m'`. Then, you can return to that position via ``` `` ```, or `<C-O>`.

Answer (score 1):

use the shortcut `` to jump back to previous cursor position. But re-using this will not take you back in cursor history but toggles between current and last cursor position.