# How to go back in vim to last cursor position

Tags: vim

To go down 17 lines of code, I can do:

- `17j`

Is there a way to go back to the previous line of code (exactly where the cursor was) instead of having to do `17k`? About half the time, if I do `ctrl-o` it will go back to the previous place, but often it does not if no editing takes place.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undo cursor movement in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688134/undo-cursor-movement-in-vim)

Comment: @mkrieger1 none of those answers work (using `,`, `;`, or `ctrl-o` which I mentioned) to go back to the last place.

Comment: @mkrieger1 it's not necessarily a 'jump' I don't think, I'm just going down with the `j` or `k` keys.

Comment: Yes. There is no other way that works in general.

Comment: @mkrieger1 hm, is there a way to customize what is contained in the jump list in vim or that's not possible?

Comment: Is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20690367/4621513) not a solution?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I think that link just lists the jump points and how to jump to a specific one but doesn't say anything about adding new event types to the jump list (or if it's possible)

Comment: So the answer is: `m'17j` and going to the marked positon is `\`\`` or `Ctrl+O`

Comment: @phd yea that seems to be the best...I wonder if I can make a macro where `NUMj` turns into `m'NUMj`(same for k)

Comment: This question might be better asked over on https://vi.stackexchange.com

Comment: FWIW, `j` and `k` are Vim's least efficient motions. Consider upgrading to jump motions if you want the benefits of the jump list: `:help jump-motions`.

Comment: @romainl but the whole point of this is that `j/k` are not included in jump motions. (I also have easy-motion installed if I want to go to a specific place.) What do you suggest would be more efficient than doing `17j` to go down 17 lines with relative line numbers then?

Comment: @David542 it is very difficult to give "the best" way to jump to another point in a buffer. There are [many different motions and ways](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2230/778). I know you want an undo/opposite motion. Generally, this means adding something to the jump list (e.g. `m'`). Personally, i think this could pollute the jump list

Comment: My whole point is that you should use jumps to move around if you want to use the jump list. You never want to go down 17 lines. What you want is to go to something that happens to be 17 lines down and going 17 lines down is indeed *one* way to go to that something. Going directly to that something with `/foo`, which *is* a jump motion, is much more intuitive and efficient.

Comment: @PeterRincker great answer, thanks for the link!

Comment: @romainl that makes sense, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Jump(jump)
    execute "normal! m'" . v:count1 . a:jump
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> j :<C-U>call Jump('j')<CR>
nnoremap <silent> k :<C-U>call Jump('k')<CR>
```